# Google spell checker not working with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Google Spell checker doesn't work on Chrome as expected. It **detects spelling mistakes**, but it doesn't prompt for correction on right-click.

Is this a bug?

Details:
Chrome Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Which word(s) does it fail to recognise/offer corrections for: a few, or every word you've tried? Which language do you use? Add this info to your question; it should assist people in answering. Cheers.

Comment: I know what the user is referring to. For years now, chrome's spell check will stop working for about a week and then on its own will start working again. This happens about every 8 months. The spell check will suggest the right correction but will not change the text when selected.

Answer (score 1):

That depends :)

If there is no suggestion close enough to that word - i.e. you type 'asduirhfdsgdssadf' -, the spell checker doesn't make any suggestion. Your context menu should show a gray "No suggestions".

It basically can tell that it's not a valid english word, but it has no idea what you meant to type.

If it's a word that you think should have a suggestion, please share what that word is. That makes it much easier to find out what's going on.

And finally, you might want to upgrade to Chrome 26 and the new spellchecker. It's pretty nice, and in most cases more accurate than the old one.