# Why are common words marked as incorrect by spell check?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Within 2 minutes of each other, I had the word `to` and the word `it's` be flagged as misspelled inside of Google Chrome. I was only able to grab a screenshot of the second occurrence.

[image]

How/why is this happening?

Comment: Related: [1](https://superuser.com/q/160288/152004), [2](https://superuser.com/q/578493/152004), [3](https://superuser.com/q/1191408/152004)

Comment: "it's" is not misspelled, but is a commonly misused word. Chrome may lump common errors like this to force people to confirm they want to use that word.

Comment: Sometimes spellcheckers try to contextualise to decide which it thinks you ought to have used, like a primitive grammar checker. Sometimes they get it right… sometimes not. it's/its & to/too are common errors. [I wish I could see the sentence you'd actually typed;)

Comment: @music2myear But why does 'Add to Dictionary' then remove the red underline? That's how I handled both of them after they popped up.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can assure you it was used in a grammatically correct manner (contraction, not showing possession, sentence structure was basic). I went to copy and paste the comment this is from, but I already deleted it (learned something new, wanted to keep answer clean).

Comment: Another example is the word operant. Like in operant conditioning. I'm given the choice between **operand**, **ope rant** (whatever that is), and again, **ope-rant** (this time with a hyphen). *Thanks google, I actually meant to type ope-rant conditioning.*